# Is there any way to link John Marshall to Andrew Johnson's impeachment?

Tags: united-states, 19th-century

I'm desperately attempting to find a way to link John Marshall to Andrew Johnson's impeachment. I'm looking for specific events, and not just his separation of powers either. I've already used the Marbury v Madison case, so I cannot directly link that either. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Marshal was a witness or participant in several early judicial impeachment cases. 
In both Presidential and Judiciary Impeachments the House impeaches and the Senate tries the case.

- Marshal was active and a participant to the impeachment proceedings against federal judge [John Pickering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Pickering_(judge)), 
  Jefferson targeted Pickering because he saw a strong judiciary as a threat to his administration.  Pickering was a strong judge, as was Marshal.  Pickering was removed from office 1804.  **[repealed judiciary acts](https://www.coursehero.com/file/p5t0sm/a-Repealed-the-Judiciary-Act-of-1801-by-Adams-midnight-appointments-2-Judicial/)**
- Marshal was a witness to the proceedings the House of Representatives (1804) impeached Associate Justice Samuel Chase,  Marshal defended Chases actions.  In 1805 Chase was acquitted by the Senate.

These judicial impeachments formed the precedent used for the first Presidential [Impeachment of Andrew Johnson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impeachment_of_Andrew_Johnson) Feb 1867.